# Is there a way to make the Raspberry Pis boot from the network

Tags: boot

I would like to make a cluster of Raspberry Pi computers.

I find it a lot of work to individually configure the images.

Is there a way that I can have the Raspberry Pis boot from the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the possibility to boot the Pi over network. While older Pis are [able to load the root file system over network](http://blogs.wcode.org/2013/09/howto-netboot-a-raspberry-pi/) (meaning you still need to have an SD card for each pi), the [RPi 3 is able to boot without SD card over network](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-ii-ethernet-all-the-awesome/). The image from the last links webpage offers a good overview:

[image]

(source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-ii-ethernet-all-the-awesome/)

Note that I haven't used network boot so far, hence I cannot say anything about filesystem consistency when accessing the same root file system by multiple Pis in parallel, etc.